# How can I find a function $g$ and a positive constant $a$ such that for all $x > 0$, $\int_a^{x^2} g(t)dt = \frac{x^3}{3} - 2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to find a function $g$ and a positive constant $a$ such that for all $x > 0$,

$$
\int_a^{x^2} g(t)dt = \frac{x^3}{3} - 2.
$$

The thing I am struggling with, is that, if the expression for $g(t)$ was given, e.g., $g(t) = 2t$, I would be able to find the derivative of the definite integral, using one of the Fundamental Theorems of Calculus, that is

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^{x^2} g(t) dt &= \frac{d}{dt}[G(x^2) - G(a)] \\
&= \frac{d}{dt}[G(x^2) - 0] \\
&= \frac{d}{dt}G(x^2) \\
&= g(x^2) \cdot 2x.
\end{align}

However, being given the actual value of the definite integral itself, and using it to find the integrand is just leaving me confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are on the correct way,

> $$
> \int_a^{x^2} g(t)dt = \frac{x^3}{3} - 2.
> $$

Do the derivative on both sides, you get:

$$g(x^2) \cdot 2x=x^2$$

Divide $2x$ on both sides, you get:

$$ g(x^2)=\frac{x}2$$

Define $t=x^2$, you get:

$$g(t)=\frac{\sqrt t}2$$

Finally, plug in the integral to determine $a$:

$$\int_a^{x^2} \frac{\sqrt t}2~dt = \frac{x^3}{3} - 2$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Hey there, but $(2)⋅2$ is already the derivative? Why should the derivative be taken again?

Comment: No, it is not taking derivative again. It is to divide $2x$ on both size. @AngMingWen

Comment: I add more steps, can you understand it now? @AngMingWen

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much.

Comment: I've accepted it as the answer.

Comment: Great, you are welcome @AngMingWen

Answer (score 2):

The chain rule is not needed. The exercise can be solved straightforward. The assumptions imply $$\int\limits_a^xg(t)\,dt ={1\over 3}x^{3/2}-2\quad (*)$$ Hence  $${1\over 3}a^{2/3}=2$$The differentation of $(*)$ gives $$g(x)={1\over 2}x^{1/2}$$